Internet cuts out after leaving laptop idle for an hour
My laptop (IdeaPad 5 15ITL05) has a reoccurring issue of internet cutting out after leaving it idle for an hour or so. It shows up as connected without internet. I have to restart my laptop for internet. How do I prevent this from happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is the closest setting I could find for power saving options. Picture 1.
This is what Opera GX (chromium) shows when such error occurs. Picture 2.

when the internet isn't work, and you try to go somewhere in the browser, what does the browser say in the bottom left corner (might be "looking up www.superuser.com" or "transfering data from ..." or a bunch of other things)?

@John I can't seem to find such setting in device manager on properties. Any detailed instructions?

@John There is no Power Manager tab per se but the closest I could find was 'MIMO Power Save Mode' as shown in the picture in the post.

@FrankThomas There is nothing that appears in the bottom left corner but what appears is shown in picture 2.
